# Is there any benefit to dumbbell flys on a flat bench vs dumbbell flys on an incline bench?

Tags: dumbbells, chest

So like the title says :

Is there any benefit to dumbbell flys on a flat bench vs dumbbell flys on an incline bench?

Does one position offer something the other does not?

Comment: Incline will work more of your upper chest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: yes.
Long answer: You have to look at it like incline and flat bench press those two targetbyour chest muscles differently (and incline uses more of your delts but puts less stress on them than a flat bench).

For starters I would recommend you to go with flat bench (as this would target most of your chest) and remember to slightly bend your elbows, hold your arms slightly forward (above your lower chest) and try to sqeeze your pectoral (chest) muscles. 
Safe training!